# Query for a json property with the highest (max) date as value in a jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres table with a jsonb column that gets inserted/updated as soon as a status is reached. I would like to query the latest status with it's date.

Given I have the following jsonb status column.

```
{
 "pending": "2018-01-12T12:34:41.785945+00:00",
 "started":"2018-01-10T15:52:41.785945+00:00",
 "processed":"2018-01-18T12:52:41.785945+00:00"
}
```

What would be the query to get?

`"processed":"2018-01-18T12:52:41.785945+00:00"`...

Basically select the property with the `max date`, Is this possible at all? And if so how would look the query?

**EDIT**: the Status JSON can have different properties at different times. So it not always the 3 'pending','started','processed'. There could only be pending or in future others.... The question is the latest status with it's date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create the table with couple of sample data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test(
id integer,  
status json  
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '{
 "pending": "2018-01-12T12:34:41.785945+00:00",
 "started":"2018-01-10T15:52:41.785945+00:00",
 "processed":"2018-01-18T12:52:41.785945+00:00"
}');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '{
 "pending": "2018-01-12T12:31:41.785945+00:00",
 "started":"2018-01-20T15:55:41.785945+00:00",
 "processed":"2018-01-10T12:20:41.785945+00:00"
}');
```

I managed to get the `max date` property by extracting values from json to a separate table, and applying typical max function and case statement to get corresponding property of interest. This probably defeats the purpose of using json type (maybe try json_type(json) instead?)

```
--- unpack values and put them into different columns
WITH t1 AS(
SELECT id, status->>'pending' AS pending, 
      status->>'started' AS started, 
      status->>'processed' AS processed       
FROM test),
--- find maximum time corresponding to each_id
t2 AS (
SELECT id, GREATEST(t1.pending, t1.processed, t1.started) AS latest
FROM t1
)
--- join to get matching column that gave latest time
SELECT t1.id, CASE WHEN t1.pending = t2.latest THEN 'pending'
                  WHEN t1.started = t2.latest THEN 'started'
                  WHEN t1.processed = t2.latest THEN 'processed' 
                  END AS max_status,
              t2.latest AS max_time
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
;
```

You can carry along other columns of interest for each `id`. This results

```
 id | max_status |             max_time             
----+------------+----------------------------------
  1 | processed  | 2018-01-18T12:52:41.785945+00:00
  2 | started    | 2018-01-20T15:55:41.785945+00:00
(2 rows)
```

**EDIT::**
After your edit, I made some changes to take care of arbitrary presence/absence of particular keys in your json field. Let's use `json_each(json)` to unpack `key, value` for each `id` to different columns

```
SELECT id, (json_each(status)).* 
FROM test
WHERE id=1;

 id |    key    |               value                
----+-----------+------------------------------------
  1 | pending   | "2018-01-12T12:34:41.785945+00:00"
  1 | started   | "2018-01-10T15:52:41.785945+00:00"
  1 | processed | "2018-01-18T12:52:41.785945+00:00"
(3 rows)
```

Not quite what we want but almost there. First thing to notice is the column names `key, value` which we can use to transform data. Second, values are `json` objects and therefore we have to take care of double quotations after casting to text. `trim` handles this nicely. Rest is to partition your data by `id`, get maximum time, and filter rows to get corresponding `status`.

```
WITH t1 AS(
    SELECT id, key as status, trim(both '"' from value::text) as time_of 
    FROM test, json_each(status)
),
t2 as(
SELECT id, status,
  to_timestamp(time_of, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as time_of,
  MAX(to_timestamp(time_of, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')) 
        OVER(PARTITION by id) AS max_time       
FROM t1)
SELECT id, status, max_time 
FROM t2
WHERE time_of = max_time;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I had to edit it which might would affect also your answer. There might be more or less 3 statuses in a column

Comment: @silverfighter Sure thing! I made some changes to reflect your edit. See above.